# Array of pointers using structs

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I'm trying to to create an array of pointers of one struct in another. I want to be able to access each block that i've allocated using this: info->array[0] and have it point to somewhere so I can free whatever it points to but he compiler says i have to dereference it..I'm not sure why because the location is a pointer and so is what I'm trying to put there. I haven't worked with pointers too much so I think there's probably something wrong with my understanding. What should i do so I don't have to dereference and can store/delete contents in the array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct numbers{
    int num1;
    int num2;
}Numbers;

typedef struct info {
    Numbers *array;
    char firstName[50];
    char lastName[50];
} Info;

int main() {
  Info *info = malloc(sizeof(Info));
  info->array = malloc(sizeof(Info*)*10);

  Numbers *num1 = malloc(sizeof(Numbers));
  info->array[0] = num1; //why dereference??
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You want `array` to be `Numbers **`.

Comment: In your definition of `Info` you have `Numbers *array`, which defines a pointer to a `Numbers` structure (or to an array of `Numbers` structures) - not a pointer to an array of pointers. So `info->array[0]` is a `Number`, not a pointer to one.

Comment: `info->array` is of type `Numbers *` (array of Numbers?), but you are allocating it as an array of `Info *`

Answer (score 0):

In your example `info->array` would be a pointer to an object of type Numbers whereas `info->array[0]` is dereferenced and is of type Numbers. So the compiler is complaining that you're assigning a "pointer to Numbers" to a "Numbers" object.
If you want `array` to point to an address of a Numbers object you would need to use a double pointer or pointer to pointer so your definition of Info would be:

```
typedef struct info {
    Numbers **array;
    char firstName[50];
    char lastName[50];
} Info;
```

then `info->array[0]` would contain a pointer to an object of type Numbers and `info->array[0] = num1` from your code would store the address of what you allocated in the array.